# What is the explanation of the equation 1-4.6 in the book "Applied Exterior Calculus"?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry

If the $n$ function $\{f^i(x^m)\}$ are of class $C^{\infty}$ in some neighborhood of $0$, then system of autonomous ODEs
$$\frac{d\bar{x}^i(t)}{dt}=f^i(\bar{x}^m(t)),\quad\quad i = 1,\cdots, n$$
has a unique solution that satisfies the initial data 
$$\bar{x}^i(0)=x^i$$
This solution may be represented by 
$$\bar{x}^i(t)=\hat{x}^i(t;x^m)=\exp\left(tf^j(x^m)\frac{\partial}{\partial x^j}\right)<x^i>, \quad\quad i=1,\cdots,n$$

Is there a way to rewrite the last formula to make it easier to understand? Can we use the formula to write down the solution as a function?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! Could you please explain better what the question is?

Comment: Questions added.